# Efficiently selecting "sub maxes" from SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Apologies for the title, I am unsure how to express my problem...
I have a table that looks something like this:

```
A     | B
--------------
01    | 1
01A   | 1
01B   | 1
01C   | 1
02    | 1
03    | 1
03    | 2
03A   | 1
03B   | 1
```

Sometimes column A is qualified with a letter (`##A,##B`), sometimes it is not (`##`).  I would need to

```
SELECT A,B from Table
```

if there were no suffixes. With the suffix, however, I need to select the maximum value of A for each B.  (That was phrased poorly).  I would expect the following results for the table above:

```
A     | B
--------------
01C   | 1
02    | 1
03    | 2
03B   | 1
```

Right now, I am using a subselect and my query is:

```
SELECT A,B FROM Table t1
WHERE t1.A = (SELECT MAX(t2.A) FROM Table t2WHERE LEFT(t1.A,2) = LEFT(t2.A,2)
```

This is incredibly inefficient, however, and my table is pretty large, so they query is taking far too long to run.  Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: There's not going to be an efficient way to do a string search for the last part of a string, then perform some logic based on that. SQL isn't intended for such functions.

Comment: You said "for each B" but you have the value of 1 in the B column 3 times. Clearly, you've not setup the problem correctly.

Comment: for each B corresponding to an unsuffixed A.  That is, for a given A, there is a set of distinct B values, and every one of these must appear one time in the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;with cteRowNumbers as (
    select A, B, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by B, left(A,2) order by A desc) as RowNumber
        from YourTable
 )
 select A, B
    from cteRowNumbers
    where RowNumber = 1
    order by A
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find common table expressions unpleasant, there's this which is essentially the same thing as the CTE example.

```
SELECT V.* 

FROM (
    SELECT
     A
    ,B
    ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY B,LEFT(A,2) ORDER BY A DESC) AS RowNumber

    FROM YourTable
) AS V

WHERE V.RowNumber = 1
```